# Retrieving a 'td' tag by searching for a 'th' tag under the same 'tr' row

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need a way to retrieve a specific 'td' tag with it's text content under a specific 'th' tag belonging to the same 'tr' row. This is how the structure looks like:

```
<tr>...Not interested in this row...</tr>
<tr>...Not interested in this row...</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Titletext</th>
    <td class="rightalign right">64663438434</td>
</tr>
<tr>...Not interested in this row...</tr>
<tr>...Not interested in this row...</tr>
```

I want to search by the 'th' tag, and retrieve the number inside the 'td' tag under it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
num  = soup.find('td', class_='rightalign right')
num.text
```

output:

```
'64663438434'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the re module.

```
import re
cells = re.findall(u"<th>Titletext</th>[^>]*>([^<]*)</td>", page)
print(cells)
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that ALL the 'td' tags have the same 'rightalign right' description, so this kinda needs to be found through the right 'th' tag, no?

Comment: Please don't advise to use `re` module for parsing XML or HTML. Both love recursive tags, and `re` hates them.

Answer (score 0):

- Using Beautiful soup you can iterate through all of the **tr's** and search for **th's**.
- Then for each **th** you can use the **find_next_sibling** method to find the next tag element.
- If this is the required **td** then extract the number

#### For example

```
import bs4

html = '<tr>...Not interested in this row...</tr> \n <tr>...Not interested in this row...</tr>\n <tr> \n <th>Titletext</th> \n <td class="rightalign right">64663438434</td> \n </tr> \n <tr>...Not interested in this row...</tr> \n <tr>...Not interested in this row...</tr>'
bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)

for tr in bs.find_all('tr'):
    for th in tr.find_all('th'):
        td = th.find_next_sibling()
        if 'class=\"rightalign right' in str(td):
            print(td.text)
```

#### Output

```
64663438434
```

Personally, I would stick with beautiful soup rather than using your own regex's as much as possible. The structure of html can be inconsistent and beautiful soup hides a lot of complexity and heavy lifting

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is kind enough to search the required elements for you:

```
value = soup.find('th', text='Titletext').findNextSibling('td').text
```

You will get a string so consider to convert it to int...

---

If the line contains more than one TD tags and you do not want the first one, but the first one with a specific class, you can add that to the request:

```
value = soup.find('th', text='Titletext').findNextSibling('td',
                  {'class': "rightalign right"}).text
```

(Thanks to ArranDuff for noticing it)

Comment: This will find the next **td** sibling of **<th>Titletext</th>** But it will not necessarily be directly the next sibling. It will also not necessarily be of the correct class. i.e **<td class="rightalign right">**

Comment: @ArranDuff: you may be right. I have edited my post. Thank you for the comment.